# Adding a CSS Pseudo Elements to center of a grid only

Tags: css

```css
.parnet{
  max-width: 600px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background: #f4f4f5;
}
.wrapper {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
}

.cell {
  position: relative;
}

.inner {
  width: 80px;
  height: 80px;
  padding: 40px;
  text-align: left;
}

.wrapper .cell:nth-child(2n):before{
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  height: 60%;
  width: 1px;
  background-color:red;
}
```

```html
<div class="parnet">
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="cell">
      <div class="inner">1</div>
    </div>
    <div class="cell">
      <div class="inner">2</div>
    </div>
    <div class="cell">
      <div class="inner">3</div>
    </div>
    <div class="cell">
      <div class="inner">4</div>
    </div>
    <div class="cell">
      <div class="inner">5</div>
    </div>
    <div class="cell">
      <div class="inner">6</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I have a grid that I'm trying to add a :before Pseudo Element to create a divider line between each grid cell. I only want the divider lines to show in the center cells and not the outside left and right.
I'm able to achieve this using border-right and then using nth-child(3n) to remove borders. But having trouble trying to do the same using a Pseudo Element

[image]

```
.parent {
      background: white;
      max-width: 600px;
      margin: 0 auto;

      .wrapper {
        display: grid;
        grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);

        .cell {
          position: relative;

          &:before {
            content: "";
            position: absolute;
            left: 0;
            top: 50%;
            transform: translateY(-50%);
            height: 60%;
            width: 1px;
            background-color:red;
          }

          &:nth-child(3n):before {
            width: 0;
          }
         .inner {
           max-width: 320px;
           width: 320px;
           height: 200px;
           padding: 57px 43px 40px;
           text-align: left;
         }
        }
      }
    }
```

Comment: Please include the full relevant example to recreate in snippet editor or codepen or something, a picture and the sass leaves a lot of work for a viewer to do to help.

Comment: what is the html with this?

Comment: Sorry never used the code snippet before, thank for the idea its really nice. Not sure why 2 people would request this post as closed ? Its a legit question and I'm doing my best to show with a photo and now code structure my issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is my answer. I'm using the `.cell:nth-child(3n):before` for the horizontal lines. I hope this is what you need.

```css
.parent {
  background: white;
  max-width: 600px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  font-size:2em;
}
.parent .wrapper {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
}
.parent .wrapper .cell {
  position: relative;
}
.parent .wrapper .cell:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  right: 50%;
  top:.2em;
  height: 60%;
  width: 1px;
  background-color: red;
}
.parent .wrapper .cell:nth-child(3n):before {
  width: 300%;
  height:1px;
  top:100%
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="wrapper">
  <div class="cell">1</div>
  <div class="cell">2</div>
  <div class="cell">3</div>
  <div class="cell">4</div>
  <div class="cell">5</div>
  <div class="cell">6</div>
  <div class="cell">7</div>
  <div class="cell">8</div>
  <div class="cell">9</div>
</div> 
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks enxaneta, I tried something like this but I have to keep right at  right: 0 not 50%. With that it works except the last one of every row has a border on its right.

Comment: So change right to 0 and then add text-align: center to .parent .wrapper .cell

Comment: Keith See my code snippet I just added to my post. I have to have a fixed with on my inner divs

Comment: Keith I just got it working based on your clue of setting right: 0. I added my code in a snippet to an answer. Thanks again for the help.

Answer (score 1):

```css
.parnet{
  max-width: 600px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background: #f4f4f5;
}
.wrapper {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
}

.cell {
  position: relative;
}

.inner {
  width: 80px;
  height: 80px;
  padding: 40px;
  text-align: left;
}

.wrapper .cell:before{
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  height: 60%;
  width: 1px;
  background-color:red;
}

.wrapper .cell:nth-child(3n):before {
  width: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="parnet">
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="cell">
      <div class="inner">1</div>
    </div>
    <div class="cell">
      <div class="inner">2</div>
    </div>
    <div class="cell">
      <div class="inner">3</div>
    </div>
    <div class="cell">
      <div class="inner">4</div>
    </div>
    <div class="cell">
      <div class="inner">5</div>
    </div>
    <div class="cell">
      <div class="inner">6</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

So the clue was to set **right: 0;** on the cell instead of left:0;
Then uses

```
.wrapper .cell:nth-child(3n):before {
  width: 0;
}
```

Thanks Keith i'm going to score your answer for giving me that great clue.